# How to get POSIX timezone string for all time zones in the world

Tags: linux, qnx

I have QNX system which accepts timezone in POSIX timezone string format (Ex: CET-1CEST,M3.5.0/2,M10.5.0/3). Is there any website/list where I can get the POSIX timezone string for all the times zones around the world

Comment: Are you looking for tzdata? https://www.iana.org/time-zones

Comment: No, I don't need the database. I want the timezone string to be used to set TZ environment variable in POSIX format

Comment: You do realise that that "database" has text files that hold exactly what you're asking for?  `awk '/^[A-Z]{2}/{print $3}' zone.tab`